# How to share files in Kubernetes from the main container to a sidecar container so that the files are not lost in the main container?

Tags: kubernetes

I use pvc and subPath in volumeMounts

```
containers:
      - image: alpine
        name: main
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/
          name: volume
          subPath: app
      - image: alpine
        name: sidecar
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/
          name: volume
          subPath: app
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-pvc
``
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

but the folder /var/www/app becomes empty (((

what am I doing wrong?

what type of volume should I use so that files from the main container are available in the sidecar container and are not overwritten ?

Comment: Don't use volumes here.  Kubernetes volume mounts act like every other Unix mount: whatever gets mounted (here the PVC) hides what was in the filesystem before (the image content) and you can't get access to it.  There's one specific case of Docker named volumes that apparently acts differently, but internally Docker copies content into the volume, and from the on the (possibly-stale) volume hides whatever was in the image.

Comment: You don't say what specifically the "app" and "sidecar" are.  Do you build both images?  In the "sidecar" Dockerfile, can you `COPY` in the content you need, so it's self-contained without needing to share files?

Comment: I think it is an issue with the indentation. Can you proper format your yaml and try again? If still no working, can you describe your pod to show how they are mounted?
Also, what is your type of PV?

Comment: @JustinYu PV is  Type:       AWSElasticBlockStore (a Persistent Disk resource in AWS).

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't want to copy files twice if they are the same

Comment: In the approach you're describing here, it seems like the thing you want to happen is still to have two copies of the files, but one in the "source" image and one in the volume.  It's an easier setup to have the two copies in the respective images and not try to manage this at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As describe on this [link](https://pauldally.medium.com/kubernetes-an-introduction-to-sidecars-21d99fbd7de3), you may try using the following yaml but I changed the volume to use [NFS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs) :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld-deployment-2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: helloworld-deployment-2
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: helloworld-deployment-2
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: www-content
        nfs:
          server: my-nfs-server.example.com
          path: /my-nfs-volume
          readOnly: true        
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: helloworld:1.0
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /www
            name: www-content
        - name: getcontent-sidecar
          image: get-content:1.0.0
          command:
          - bash
          - -c
          - |
            git clone https://github.com/psdally/k8s-sidecars.git /www
            while true; do
              git fetch
              sleep 60
            done
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /www
            name: www-content
```